How do I completely suppress connection errors from requests and urllib3 in Python?
I'm using the requests library in Python to make HTTP requests, and I'm encountering connection errors such as Max retries exceeded and Failed to establish a new connection. These errors are being printed to the console despite my efforts to suppress them.
I tried several approaches, such as, suppressing logs from urllib3 and requests using the logging module, Ignoring warnings using the warnings module, Wrapping requests with try/except blocks to handle exceptions silently.
However, the errors still appear in the console like this:
Error fetching https://TEST.com/sites/default/modules/advanced_comment_trigger/LICENSE.txt with method GET: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='TEST.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /sites/default/modules/advanced_comment_trigger/LICENSE.txt (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x102bd1a00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known'))

My code:
import os
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import logging
import warnings
import threading
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning, module='urllib3')
logging.getLogger("urllib3").setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
logging.getLogger("requests").setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)

DEBUG = False
MAX_WORKERS = 20  
MIN_WORKERS = 1 
WORKER_DECREMENT = 5 
lock = threading.Lock() 

def create_retry_session():
    session = requests.Session()
    retries = Retry(total=3, backoff_factor=0.1, status_forcelist=[429, 500, 502, 503, 504])
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries)
    session.mount('http://', adapter)
    session.mount('https://', adapter)
    return session

def load_drupal_modules(db_file='databases/drupal'):

    drupal_modules = []
    
    try:
        with open(db_file, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                parts = line.strip().split(',')
                if len(parts) == 2:
                    drupal_modules.append({
                        'test_id': parts[0].strip().strip('"'), 
                        'module': parts[1].strip().strip('"')  
                    })
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return drupal_modules
    
    return drupal_modules

def is_drupal_site(url, fetch_url, user_agent):
    response = fetch_url(url, method="GET", headers={"User-Agent": user_agent})
    
    if response:
        if 'X-Generator' in response.headers and 'Drupal' in response.headers['X-Generator']:
            return True
        
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        meta_generator = soup.find('meta', attrs={'name': 'Generator'})
        if meta_generator and 'Drupal' in meta_generator.get('content', ''):
            return True
        
        drupal_paths = ['/user', '/node', '/CHANGELOG.txt', '/sites/default/files/']
        for path in drupal_paths:
            check_url = url + path
            check_response = fetch_url(check_url, method="HEAD", headers={"User-Agent": user_agent})
            if check_response and check_response.status_code == 200:
                return True

    return False

def check_module(url, fetch_url, user_agent, module, module_path="/sites/default/modules"):
    module_url = f"{module_path}/{module['module']}/LICENSE.txt"
    full_url = url.lower() + module_url  

    if DEBUG:
        print(f"+ Testing URL: {full_url}")

    try:
        response = fetch_url(full_url, method="GET", headers={"User-Agent": user_agent})

        if response and response.status_code == 200 and 'LICENSE' in response.text:
            return f"+ {full_url}: Drupal module {module['module']} found.\n    test ID: {module['test_id']}"

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        reduce_thread_count()

    return None 

def reduce_thread_count():
    global MAX_WORKERS
    with lock:  
        if MAX_WORKERS > MIN_WORKERS:
            MAX_WORKERS = max(MIN_WORKERS, MAX_WORKERS - WORKER_DECREMENT)  # Reduce thread count
            if DEBUG:
                print(f"- Reducing thread count to {MAX_WORKERS}")

def enumerate_drupal_modules(url, fetch_url, user_agent, module_path="/sites/default/modules"):
    drupal_modules = load_drupal_modules()

    if not drupal_modules:
        return 

    found_vulnerability = False
    completed_tests = [] 

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_WORKERS) as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(check_module, url, fetch_url, user_agent, module, module_path) for module in drupal_modules]
    
        for future in as_completed(futures):
            result = future.result()
            completed_tests.append(result)
            if result:
                print(result)
                found_vulnerability = True

    if not found_vulnerability:
        print("+ Test completed. None of the tested files returned any results.")

def run(url, fetch_url, user_agent, detected_server):
    if is_drupal_site(url, fetch_url, user_agent):
        print(f"+ Detected Drupal, proceeding with module enumeration.")
        module_path = "/sites/default/modules"
        enumerate_drupal_modules(url, fetch_url, user_agent, module_path)


Looks like you might try catching urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError in whatever fetch_url() is or alternatively wherever you use it.

see also: Cannot catch requests.exceptions.ConnectionError with try except
